# Why python telethon giving semaphore error while connecting with telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am using following code to connect to telegram with python telethon. But I am getting "**<class 'OSError'> during disconnect: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired**" this error..

```
import configparser
import json
import time
import re
import telethon.sync
from array import *
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChannel
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import (GetHistoryRequest)
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
client = TelegramClient('abcd', 12345, 'khgkj4hkjh42kj4h2k4jhg')
client.start()
print("connected")
time.sleep(2)
client.disconnect()
```

The DEBUG log is as below;

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using proactor: IocpProactor
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 1...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection success!
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:New auth_key attempt 1...
INFO:telethon.network.connection.connection:The server closed the connection
INFO:telethon.network.connection.connection:<class 'OSError'> during disconnect: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired
WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection error 1 during auth_key gen: ConnectionError: Not connected
INFO:telethon.network.connection.connection:<class 'OSError'> during disconnect: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expirede here
```

Comment: You're likely experiencing connection issues to the Telegram servers.

Comment: I tried multiple internet service providers

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys it was indeed an internet connection issue. confirmed it with VPN. All the ISPs in my country has blocked telegram.